# Переменная внутри выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, winforms, powershell

Имеются контролы на форме, по которым нужно производить поиск внутри функции, для этого решил воспользоваться Controls.Find, на вход функции приходит $name. В данном случае нужно произвести поиск именно по TextBox и занести в массив для дальнейшей работы. Имена TextBox представлены, например, как IPTextBox1, IPTextBox2 и т.д. Как я написал и как не работает (NetworkForm - форма, на которой все и содержится):

```
$TextBoxes = $NetworkForm.Controls.Find('/^([regex]::escape($name))[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{3}[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2}.{1}$/', 1)
```

Прошу вашей помощи

Answer (score 0):

Я не понял, что вы пытаетесь сделать с помощью регекса.

Но вот вам полный пример скрипта, создающего форму с тремя текстбоксами на ней. Обратите внимание, двум из них присвоено одинаковое имя: 'IPTextBox'. Благодаря этому, метод Find находит их двоих по этому имени.

```cs
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
add-type -Assembly system.windows.forms

$NetworkForm = New-Object Form

$IPTextBox1 = New-Object TextBox
$IPTextBox1.Name = 'IPTextBox'

$IPTextBox2 = New-Object TextBox
$IPTextBox2.Name = 'IPTextBox'
$IPTextBox2.Top = 50

$SomeTextBox = New-Object TextBox
$SomeTextBox.Top = 100

$NetworkForm.Controls.Add($IPTextBox1)
$NetworkForm.Controls.Add($IPTextBox2)
$NetworkForm.Controls.Add($SomeTextBox)

$NetworkForm.Add_Load({
    $name = 'IPTextBox'
    $TextBoxes = $NetworkForm.Controls.Find($name, $false)
    $NetworkForm.Text = $TextBoxes.Length

    foreach ($tb in $TextBoxes)
    {
        $tb.Text = ++$i;
    }
})

$NetworkForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: стоило яснее объяснить суть задачи. На вход функции может прийти любой текст. У меня ряд контролов, названных IP/DNS/MaskTextBox, осуществлять поиск нужно именно по тому, что пришло на вход, а не именно по IP. Загвоздка в том, что неправильно написан regex, потому что я не знаю как правильно использовать [regex]::escape(). А использую я его для того, чтобы добавить переменную внутрь regex. То есть чтобы поиск был Controls.Find([$name]TextBox, $true), где $name может быть чем угодно